# CardView Design is not appear Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My CardView design is not properly appearing in Xamarin android project. It's gives me a alert "could not load controls form the android support library". Though I've added all support libraries. I really can't find the missing libraries now.

I've a imageview and some other textview under the CardView which is not appearing in design. but runs the project without having any issues.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[![Here is my design preview. It's just showing the text CardView][1]][1]

Here is the libraries
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your project may have migrated to AndroidX.

Try to install `Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView` nuget package and use

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    ...
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

or install `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` nuget package and use

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    ...
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked !!!!!!!

But How it's get migrated to AndroidX??

Comment: @rykamol About [AndroidX migration in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration),you could read it.